# Why do the tracked tag badges sort by number of answers?

Tags: support, tag-badges, badge-progress

On Stack Overflow, when I go into the Activity tab in my profile and select "track my next tag badge", I notice that the recommended tag is [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript). It's rather odd, because my *score* for that tag is -2. Looking over the list makes it quite obvious that they are sorted by the number of *answers* that I've posted, rather than my *score*. Even weirder is that when I scroll down to "top tags", the tags there *are* sorted by score rather than answers. Why does it work like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the 'Track my next tag badge' dialog, the tags are sorted by the *average* progress of the two bars (score and # of answers). As you need *both* to satisfy the criteria for the tag badge, this is the only viable sorting option.

In your case, if you manage to post one single genius answer to a JavaScript question scoring 50 points, you're already halfway the badge.