# Tag badge not found in "Next tag badge"

Tags: bug, profile-page, tag-badges, badge-progress

I am trying to select a tag badge that I wish to track with the *Next tag badge* cog on my profile page.
The particular tag I am interested in tracking is not presented in the list, nor does it show up in the *Search for a badge* feature.
**Why isn't it there?**

When I look  in the *Tags* tab on the activity page, it shows my stats for this tag are:  "12 score 8 posts" (including 1 question).  This should be enough to show up on the *Next tag badge* list —
especially when at the bottom of the list there are several tags that have: "0/100 score 0/80 answers" (e.g. 1 question).

I assume that this is related to the issue raised (but unanswered) in this post:
[Tag Badges with empty stats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378517/tag-badges-with-empty-stats)
**How is the *Next tag badge* list populated?**

---

The answer to this related question:  [Why do the tracked tag badges sort by number of answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281860/why-do-the-tracked-tag-badges-sort-by-number-of-answers)
doesn't seem to be being applied, or something else is causing problems.

The particular tag in question is relatively new (almost a month old), but this should be more that enough time for it to work properly.

Comment: TL;DR: *A tag must appear on a minimum of 100 questions to be considered for tag badges.* (copied from the dupe answer.)

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard - One Hundred! That's the answer then. So far it only has a total of 57 questions.

Comment: Yeah, you can start a new feature request asking to adjust the 100 per-site, so that on smaller sites it would have badge faster. But it would not likely be done any time soon.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard - I created the tag a month or so ago and have been slowing tagging in old questions, as advised in: [The system for adding a new tag to old questions is broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379993/the-system-for-adding-a-new-tag-to-old-questions-is-broken). It's taking a long time but I think 100 is a reasonable minimum (if there needs to be a minimum).  There are easily a hundred more questions I can and will tag in eventually.